# How can I define two values for drop-down button choices?

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I want to define 2 different value for choices in drop-down button and put them in different formula?
For example first choice has two value like 8 and 0.2? I want to put 8 in first formula and 0.2 in second value. (assume grade 1 to 4 are another variable that user puts). I want to print both variable total and result.

```
<select id="SelectPaint">
  <option value="8">1</option>
  <option value="8">2</option>
  <option value="13">3  </option>
  <option value="14">4 </option>
  <option value="13">5</option>
  <option value="10">6</option>
  <option value="12">7</option>
 </select>
```

My function is;

```
var grade6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('SelectPaint').value * 1);
 
var total = (grade1 +grade2+ grade3 + grade4 )/grade6(First value);

var result = total/grade6(second value)
```

And for example grade 1 is:

```
<p style="font-family:calibri">T<b></b><input type="number" id="assign1" value="" name="onlynumbers" required><span class="required">*</span></p> 
var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign1').value * 1);
```

Comment: So user will select only 1 option but in the hindsight you need to get 2 values for that selection?

Comment: @Anurag Sinha, Exactly.

Comment: grade6 seems to be the value selected in above dropdown. What are grade1, grade2, grade3 and grade4 here? From where are they coming?

Comment: Yes @Anurag. grade1, grade2, grade3 and grade4 are numbers that user put in special fields. like<p style="font-family:calibri">T<b></b><input type="decimal" id="assign1"  value="" name="onlynumbers" required><span class="required">*</span></p> and var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assign1').value * 1);

Comment: FWIW, "decimal" is not a valid input type; it'll default back to "text." `type="number"` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I pu my function in my question body and change "decimal" to "number". Is it possible to help me how my functions delimit these values?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to attach 2 values to the `<option>`. You get a single value and then have a map somewhere in your JS for the other value.

If you still need to get 2 values directly then concat both the value with some separator and later parse it. Something like `<option value="8_0.2">1</option>`. When user selects `1` you get `8_0.2`, you parse it to get both the values : `value.split("_")` (not a recommended approach though).

Comment: How I can do sth like that you have mentioned? (You get a single value and then have a map somewhere in your JS for the other value) If I defined 2 values, how can I mention that in first formula use one of them and in another formula use second one?   @AnuragSinha

Comment: I don't think I get it completely. May be add some example on what exactly are you trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
For example first choice has two value like 8 and 0.2? I want to put 8 in first formula and 0.2 in second value.
```

I would include both values in the value attribute and delimit them with a comma, pipe, underscore, etc. Then your function can delimit and parse as needed. It's already a string needing to be parsed in the Javascript, so it shouldn't be a big deal to have to parse both.

`<option value="8|0.2">1</option>`

`function parser(valueString) {const firstVal = valueString.split("|")[0];const secondVal = valueString.split("|")[1];otherStuff();}`

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how my code realize where should it use any values? How I should define them in formula?

Comment: What's your function that will handle these values? You will have to pass them to your handler function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute for your problem. data attribute can keep your second value and you can reach that data which option you selected.

```
<select id="SelectPaint">
  <option value="8" data-second="1">1</option>
  <option value="8" data-second="2">2</option>
  <option value="13" data-second="3">3  </option>
  <option value="14" data-second="4">4 </option>
  <option value="13" data-second="5">5</option>
  <option value="10" data-second="6">6</option>
  <option value="12" data-second="7">7</option>
 </select>
```

Use it, It will solve your problem. You can reach your second data using

```
$(selected-option).attr('data-second').val()
```

Comment: So for second value, should I define new variable? For example `grade7=$(selected-option).attr('data-second').val()` and then use in formula.  @Enver